# BannerPlugin error in Webpack 2.2.1

Tags: webpack

Since updating webpack to 2.2.1, I'm getting this error while building the project:

```
Error: BannerPlugin only takes one argument (pass an options object)
```

This is how I use the plugin:

```
plugins: [
new webpack.DefinePlugin(GLOBALS),
new webpack.BannerPlugin('require("source-map-support").install();',
  { raw: true, entryOnly: false }),
```

],

Can't figure our what I'm doing wrong, seems to be ok according to documentation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Take a look at https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#bannerplugin-breaking-change.  This was the only documentation I could find on the change.  The first string argument in your version moves into the config object as a "banner" property.

```
new webpack.BannerPlugin({banner: 'require("source-map-support").install();', raw: true, entryOnly: false})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I totally missed this. It was indeed the culprit.

Comment: Running the builded code i get this error `require(...).install(...) is not a function` any tip?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#bannerplugin-breaking-change > returns a 404